# Is there a way to implement a lock-free solution to ensure the data integrity across multiple instances

Tags: java, mysql, locking, data-synchronization

I am running multiple instances of a java application, and all those instances are connected to one mysql database, I came a cross a problem where I have some data (numerical) that I want to ensure the integrity of.

For example I got a request on instance A saying that the value should be incremented by 5, and at the same time another request on instance B incremented the value by 1, and so on...

I have been looking at different implementations for my problem, and so far all of them used some sort of a locking mechanism, for example this piece of code is what I currently have.

```
    protected Lock getLock(String seqName) {
        Lock oldLock, dbSequenceLock = dbSequenceLocks.get(seqName)
        if (dbSequenceLock == null) {
            dbSequenceLock = new ReentrantLock()
            oldLock = dbSequenceLocks.putIfAbsent(seqName, dbSequenceLock)
            if (oldLock != null) return oldLock
        }
        return dbSequenceLock
    }

     protected String update(String seqName, int value) {
        try{
            Lock dbSequenceLock = getDbSequenceLock(seqName)
            dbSequenceLock.lock()
            Type record = selectForUpdate(seqName);//This selects the 
            entity for update
            record.set("val", record.get("val") + val);//increment or decrement the value...
            record.update();
        } finally {
            dbSequenceLock.unlock()
        }
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to do this, and if I can get rid of the locking somehow, any suggestions?

Comment: If you execute a query with `UPDATE table SET val = val + 5 WHERE ...`, the database will do this for you.

Comment: I like the idea, but what happens if I have a lot of updates?, I already implemented this solution once, and ended up with many wait timeout exceeded, even though the query was as simple as the update above.

Comment: The database has to do the locking. If you have several updates, consider combining them, use an explicit transaction around them, see how the database can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're maintaining the ACIDity of the database, these transactions will be in isolation of each other. So, unless you have very slow queries for updates, it won't matter. The query that runs later will update the record and it will persist.

The easiest but inefficient solution would be to push your changes in a queue and execute them one after another. This way, you can track which of the changes was done earlier and which was done later. You can also use Redis's feature of atomic increment wherein you can push your changes for that variable concurrently and only the latest one will persist. Obviously, this means that there won't be immediate consistency but only eventual consistency.